# How can I attach an object with another object in CoreData using a one to many relationship?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

[image][image]

I'm pretty good at working with core data when using entities by themselves, but since I've started playing with relationships I've hit a few walls that I can't seem to climb over even after trying to find a solution for many days. I've got an entity called "EntityOne" -for simplicity reasons- as well as a second "EntityTwo" entity. EntityOne has a one-to-many relationship with EntityTwo. Basically I'm trying to attach one or more EntityTwo objects to EntityOne when saving to my managedObjectContext, without saving EntityOne first then attaching EntityTwo objects to it after fetching results. How can I attach both of them together when saving to the persistent store?

This is my declaration of both entity descriptions and managedObjects.

```
let firstEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("EntityOne", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
let firstItem = NSManagedObject(entity: firstEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)

let secondEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("EntityTwo", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
let secondItem = NSManagedObject(entity: secondEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
```

Usually when not working with relationships I would save objects like so:

```
    firstItem.attributeOne = titleTextField.text
    managedObjectContext?.save(&error)
```

or

```
firstItem.setValue("\(titleTextField.text)", forKey: "attributeOne"
managedObjectContext?.save(&error)
```

So let's say that on the same viewController I have all the data needed to create an object for EntityOne and one or more objects of type EntityTwo to attach to that EntityOne object, how would I proceed to doing so? Thanks so much in advance to all of those who help. Cheers!

Comment: What have you tried already to associate `EntityTwo` with `EntityOne`? What does your model look like?

Comment: Well since EntityOne's relationship with EntityTwo is of type NSSet, I figured that I would have to create an array consisting of one or more EntityTwo objects that I want to attach with an EntityOne object and store it using firstItem.relationshipW/EntityTwo = [EntityTwo objects array]. For some reason it's not working.

Comment: I added pictures if it can help in any way. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to set the relationship "from the other direction" since it is to-one:

```
secondItem.entityOne = firstItem
```

But that doesn't really answer your question.  The to-many relationship is represented as NSSet, so you could use:

```
firstItem.entityTwo = NSSet(object: secondItem)
```

or

```
firstItem.entityTwo = NSSet(array: [secondItem, thirdItem])
```

which is fine if you are starting with no related items, but to add an item to an existing set:

```
var myRelatedItems : NSMutableSet = firstItem.mutableSetValueForKey("entityTwo")
myRelatedItems.addObject(secondItem)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works like a charm and I've also figured how to retrieve the objects from the array stored in the NSSet relationship with NSFethedResultsController.